# The encryption program is printing [] instead of ['h''e''l''l''o']

Tags: python

if anyone saw my last question, its pretty similar, if not here's some context. making an encryption program and I want it to shift by three, I made this code in another program and it worked flawlessly
but now that its in a function it just print [] instead of for example ['k''h''o''o''r']

here is the code:

```
from os import sys
import random
plaintext =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

print ("--------- M A I N   M E N U ---------")
print ()

userchoice = input("""
1 - Generate Random Key
2 - Encrypt file
3 - Decrypt file
4 - Quit

""")

def option123():

    if (userchoice == '1'):
        num1 = random.randint(1, 25)
        print("Random key: ", num1)
        
    if (userchoice == '2'):
        encrypt(plaintext,key)

userentry = input("Enter message to encrypt: ").lower()
key=[]

def encrypt(plaintext,key):
    for letter in userentry:
        if letter == " ":
            key += letter
        elif plaintext.index(letter) + 3 >= len (plaintext):
            key += plaintext[plaintext.index(letter) + 3 - 26]
        else:
            
            key += plaintext[plaintext.index(letter) + 3]

print(key)
```

---

here is the output:

```
--------- M A I N   M E N U ---------


1 - Generate Random Key
2 - Encrypt file
3 - Decrypt file
4 - Quit

2
Enter message to encrypt: hello
[]
```

Comment: You are doing `key=[]` and then `print(key)` without modifying `key`. The code appears to be doing exactly what you told it to do. I think you've missed a step somewhere.

Comment: You define `key=[]` and then you do `print(key)`. Why would you expect a different result?

Comment: tbh I have no idea, looking back at it it didnt make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call your `encrypt` function, so the `key` list remains equal to `[]` which is what is printed out in `print(key)`.

Comment: ah I am dumb, it works now thanks Dapperduck <3

Comment: @Alsrulez No problem! If my answer worked, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. Thanks!